# CoreOS で起動していた Docker コンテナがいつの間にか停止している

Tags: docker, coreos

コンテナを停止したつもり無いのですが、勝手に終了していました。`docker ps`で表示されず、`docker ps -a`　でみると、数時間前に停止してしまっているような状況です。ログ等がどこにあるかも分からず、どうしたものか苦戦しております。

何を見ると Docker のコンテナの挙動が分かるものでしょうか？

環境は CoreOS on GCE です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

coreosであれば`sudo journalctl -u docker`などでdockerのログが見れるはずです。
またコンテナが停止したのは多分CoreOSの自動アップデートによって
インスタンスが再起動した為と考えられます。
※stableが2015/02/04、alphaが2015/02/05あたりにアップデートされており、GCE上のImageもそれぞれ新しいバージョンが作成されています。

fleetなどを利用してコンテナが自動再起動するように設定すれば自動的に再起動するようになるはずです。

Comment: ありがとうございます！まさにその通りのようでした。さすが！